# Laravel Authorize() confusion

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm currently migrating a project from CodeIgniter to Laravel5.

I saw in Laracasts that you can use the `Request::authorize()` method to authorize access before the controller is called, and it returns true or false.

This would (I think) be the ideal solution as I can contain permission checks within the request, rather than pollute the controller with permission checks and redirections / responses.

The only problem is, when I return `false` from `authorize()`, it simply loads an empty white page with `forbidden` written, and I can't find any documentation on laravel.com on how to template it (either there is no documentation, or I'm overlooking it)

I know I can edit the 404 page in `errors/404.blade.php`, but I can't work out how to customize the 403 page, which I've tried to add a custom `403.blade.php` page, which doesn't get displayed. ( https://mattstauffer.co/blog/laravel-5.0-custom-error-pages )

Is placing these permission checks in the Request a good idea? Or am I missing something?

**Update**
I ran a backtrace from `authorize()`, and it looks like it throws an `UnauthorizedException`, which extends `RuntimeException`. I've tried catching both in the `routes.php` file, which doesn't work either.

I've also tried to create middleware, and call the middleware from a method, which doesn't work either, since the middleware's not even called at all.

**Update 2**
Ok, so I found out that I can only call `$this->middleware()` from the constructor, not individual methods, which is progress, I guess.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What i do is add a `forbiddenResponse()` method to Request abstract class. You can return a response object from that method to render a human readable error.

```
namespace App\Http\Requests;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;
use Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse;

abstract class Request extends FormRequest {

    public function forbiddenResponse()
    {
        return new JsonResponse('Unauthorized', 403);
        // or return Response::make('Unauthorized', 403);
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry it's taken me a while to get back, I've been working on other stuff. I've just tested your method and it works brilliantly, and is much more simplier than what I was doing before! Thank you very much for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Check the `app\Exceptions\Handler.php` file. That's where you can customize your exception handling.

The 403 error launches a `HttpException`. By default, Laravel will look under your `resources\views\errors\` directory and try to find a view that corresponds to the same status code. Since you already said that you've created a file called `403.blade.php` inside that folder, it should render this page for 403 errors.

One last thing, remember to check inside your web server config file (`httpd.conf` for Apache, `sites-available\your-host` for Nginx), if you have a default behavior for any error. If you're using Homestead, you can check the Nginx config file for anything like `error_page 404 /index.php;`, comment the line and restart the service. That's not the ideal scenario but usually works.

Comment: Unfortunately this isn't working either. I forced an error in the authorize() method which produced a backtrace. After following it back, upon failure of authorize(), it only throws a `UnauthorizedException` which extends `RuntimeException`. I've tried catching both in the routes.php file which doesn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

Override the method within your form request object

```
class CreateUserRequest extends FormRequest {

    public function forbiddenResponse(){
        return abort(403);

    }
}
```